# How to write Select Function in AZURE EASY API

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Below is the code which I used to get data from a table. This piece of code works properly in azure classic(OLD) portal. But in New portal it doesn't seem to work. I tried all possible syntax to do that but nothing worked.
Help appreciated!!

```
someTable.select('id','Name')}).read({
        success: function(results) {
         //rest of the code
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using Easy Tables (I'm not familiar with that API), as this how-to does? https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/

Answer (score 4):

Finally after spending so many days i found the answer.

In azure new portal,they have changed the syntax of writing Easy table script and Api script(Custom API). And i hope my answer will help You.

```
request.azureMobile.tables('someTable').select('id','name').where({ 
// your conditions

}).read().then(function (results) {
           //rest of the code
          }
 });
```

If you found any trouble in Azure New Portal check the link given below.

https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/